# Is the draw weighted?

Tags: dota-autochess

When I start getting for exemple a couple of goblins, their draw rate seems to plummet, and I have a hard time getting any more.
And it seems to do it for every race.

So is the draw weighted in some way (for exemple to make stacking 1 or 2 races more risky), or is it just rotten luck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All chess pieces are drawn from a finite pool shared by all players, which according to [this analysis](https://www.reddit.com/r/AutoChess/comments/ai7nvq/dac_code_analysis_from_vpk_hero_pool_sizes/) contains

- 45 copies of 1-cost pieces
- 30 copies of 2-cost pieces
- 25 copies of 3-cost pieces
- 15 copies of 4-cost pieces
- 10 copies of 5-cost pieces

If a player buys a certain piece, it's removed from the pool for all players, including themself.

That said, in the early rounds it's mostly just RNG and confirmation bias. You're hoping for pieces that will synergize with the ones you already have, so you're more likely to remember the times when you don't get what you want.